# Check which URL you're on right now

Tags: php

I want to check which URL someone is currently on. For example:

```
if(url=index.php?p=contact) {
    echo the code i want to run, 
}
else {
    do nothing 
}
```

So basically, I want to run a block of code when the user is on `index.php?p=contact`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check the complete path, see [Gumbo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390005/check-which-url-youre-on-right-now/3390017#3390017). If `index.php` is only accessible by navigating to that name directly (that is, you know if `index.php` is being executed the user must've gone to `index.php`, and you're not using something like URL rewriting), it probably makes much more sense to just check:

```
if($_GET['p'] == 'contact')
```

within `index.php`. If the condition is being reached, `index.php` is executing and clearly that's the page the user is on

Answer (score 4):

The current requested URI path plus query is available in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and the filename of the processing script in `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`.

Comment: So, 


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "index.php?p=contact") {
code
}


it should work ?

Comment: @Andre: The URI path does always begin with a `/`. So the value would rather be `/index.php?p=contact`. But that must be the actually requested URI. If you use some rewriting techniques the external/internal URI may differ.

Comment: @Andre: Oh, and if you just want to test if some specific URI query parameter is set, use `isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] === 'contact'` to test it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did (to make it as I want with .htaccess); works for me since I do not have allot of pages to check. I used PHP_SELF:

```
<?php
if (htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) === "/.../index.php") { // echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] to see your path ..
            header("Location: ./"); // I am using .htaccess, so I only want the page name and exclude ".php" in the address-bar (URL)
            die();
        } else if (htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) === "/.../page2.php") {
            header("Location: page2"); // I am using .htaccess, so I only want the page name and exclude ".php" in the address-bar (URL)
            die();
        }
?>
```